# Changing the first letter of every line in a file to uppercase

Tags: bash, case, unicode-string

I need to change the first letter of every line in a file to uppercase, e.g.

```
the bear ate the fish.
the river was too fast.
```

Would become:

```
The bear ate the fish.
The river was too fast.
```

- The document contains some special letters: a, a, á, à, ǎ, ā, b, c, d, e, e, é, è, ě, ē, f, g, h, i, i, í, ì, ǐ, ī, j, k, l, m, n, o, o, ó, ò, ǒ, ō, p, q, r, s, t, u, u, ú, ù, ǔ, ü, ǘ, ǜ, ǚ, ǖ, ū, v, w, x, y, and z.
- The uppercase forms of these letters are: A, A, Á, À, Ǎ, Ā, B, C, D, E, E, É, È, Ě, Ē, F, G, H, I, I, Í, Ì, Ǐ, Ī, J, K, L, M, N, O, O, Ó, Ò, Ǒ, Ō, P, Q, R, S, T, U, U, Ú, Ù, Ǔ, Ü, Ǘ, Ǜ, Ǚ, Ǖ, Ū, V, W, X, Y, and Z.

How can I change the first letter of every line in the file to uppercase?

Comment: I think what Engineer meant was what programming language. PHP, etc.

Comment: BASH would be preferred.

Comment: The question is tagged 'bash'...

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the 'bash' tag. I removed my PHP answers.

Comment: I am afraid none of the solutions actually work for you, I just realize your character set requirement is in unicode. It means the input file is in a format we don't really know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed  's/^\(.\)/\U\1/' yourfile > convertedfile
```

Little explanation:

- the `^` represents the start of a line.
- `.` matches any character
- `\U` converts to uppercase
- `\( ... \)` specifies a section to be referenced later (as `\1` in this case); parentheses are to be escaped here.

Do **not** try to redirect the output to the same file in one command (i.e. <s>`> yourfile`</s>) as you will lose your data. If you want to replace in the same file then check out joelparkerhenderson's answer.

Comment: Works a treat, thank you for a simple effective solution.

Answer (score 7):

```
pearl.311> cat file1
linenumber11
linenumber2  
linenumber1
linenumber4
linenumber6
pearl.312> awk '{print toupper(substr($0,1,1))""substr($0,2)}' file1
Linenumber11
Linenumber2  
Linenumber1
Linenumber4
Linenumber6
pearl.313>
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a few sed answers with `s/^\(.\)/\U\1/`. GNU sed also has a `\u` directive that changes only the next letter to uppercase, so

```
sed 's/./\u&/'
```

Although if the first character on a line is a space, you won't see an uppercase letter, so

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/\u&/'
```

Comment: I'd say this is the better answer.

Answer (score 2):

To change the file in place:

```
sed -i -e 's/^\(.\)/\U\1/' file.txt
```

Comment: Works! But also, Why do I also get the error(warning??) : sed: can't read : No such file or directory?

Comment: @bikashg you got the error because there was a typo in my answer-- sorry-- I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your special characters in place of a-z and A-Z

```
function up { local c="$1" ; echo -e "$c" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' ; }
while read line
do
  echo $(up ${line:0:1})${line:1}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure `bash`:

```
while read x ; do echo "${x^*}" ; done < inputfile > outputfile
```

---

Test/demo (remove the code after `done` for more complete output):

```
for f in a, a, á, à, ǎ, ā, b, c, d, e, e, é, è, ě, ē, f, g, h, i, i, í, ì, ǐ, ī, \
         j, k, l, m, n, o, o, ó, ò, ǒ, ō, p, q, r, s, t, \
         u, u, ú, ù, ǔ, ü, ǘ, ǜ, ǚ, ǖ, ū, v, w, x, y, and z.
do  echo "$f foo bar." ; done | 
while read x ; do echo "${x^*}" ; done | head -15 | tail -6
```

Output:

```
E, foo bar.
E, foo bar.
É, foo bar.
È, foo bar.
Ě, foo bar.
Ē, foo bar.
```