# How to capitalize first letter of each line in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, uppercase, capitalization

I'm looking for a command that capitalizes the first letter of each line in bash.

Actually I used this command:

```
sed 's/^\(.\)/\U\1/'
```

But I need to use another command instead of "\U".
.

Comment: Why can't you use `\U`?

Comment: wrt `I need to use another command instead of "\U"` - so we don't waste time suggesting them, what other perfectly reasonable solutions can you not use? Do you have any other non-obvious requirements (e.g. it can't be perl or it's got to be sed or it can't be GNU sed or it can't be shell or it can only be shell builtins or it can only be sed or awk or.....)? Do your lines always start with letters or can they start with numbers or punctuation and if so then what do you want to happen? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output plus your full requirements

Comment: @Pedro Only the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10008858/3220113 meets the requirements.

Answer (score 9):

Why do you need to use something else than `\U`?

You can use `\u` which only capitalizes one letter:

```
sed 's/./\u&/'
```

Or, use parameter expansion:

```
while read line ; do echo "${line^}" ; done
```

Comment: It's for an assignment - we were asked to use it without any '\u' or '\U'. The instructor asked us to use something like '[:upper:]'. I just don't find any other way to represent it.

Comment: `[:upper:]` is a POSIX character class used in regexps for matching upper case letters in a locale-independent way. It has nothing to do with converting letters to upper case.

Comment: This appears to be a GNU extension. It doesn't work with e.g. BSD sed.

Answer (score 1):

Split your file in first character/rest of line, upper the first and paste te columns together.

```
paste -d "" <(cut -c1 inputfile| tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') <(cut -c2- inputfile)
```

EDIT:
When you want to parse input from a stream (like `mycommand | myscript.sh`), my original solution will cause problems. My solution wants to parse the input twice. When you can wait until the input process is finished, you can redirect the output to a tmp file

```
tmpfile=/tmp/myscript.wrk
# read input with cat
cat > ${tmpfile}
paste -d "" <(cut -c1 ${tmpfile}| tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') <(cut -c2- ${tmpfile})
rm -f ${tmpfile} 2>/dev/null
```

You can try the same on a commandline. Withot the sleep, the second cut will find an empty file. The sleep of 1 second will fail when the original command runs for more than a second

```
mycommand | tee /tmp/dont_do_this | 
   cut -c1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | 
   paste -d "" - <(sleep 1;cut -c2- /tmp/dont_do_this)
```

Reviewing the above solutions will lead to the conclusion that you should use a solution like @choroba posted. When the instructor says you should use `[:lower:]` is like asking if you want to have coffee and add that you should drink it through your nose: possible but not nice.
When you really like to do this, try the next solution:

```
mycommand | while read -r line; do
   printf "%s%s\n" $(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< "${line:0:1}") "${line:1}"
done
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for - just using paste command. I just need it from Standard output and not from a files. How should I write it?

Comment: Using standard input asks for a different approach. Splitting the input and joining the two threads needs a line-oriented approach. Or `awk`.

Answer (score -1):

this is a simple way that work fine:
**sed -e 's/^./\U&/' yourfile**

Comment: OP Says: `But I need to use another command instead of "\U". .`